# Why are these functions not defined, and does this work? How do I debug this?

Tags: python

I need help with this problem:

Implement the roll_dice function in hog.py. It takes two arguments: a positive integer called num_rolls giving the number of dice to roll and a dice function. It returns the number of points scored by rolling the dice that number of times in a turn: either the sum of the outcomes or 1 (Sow Sad).

The Sow Sad rule:

Sow Sad. If any of the dice outcomes is a 1, the current player's score for the turn is 1.

To obtain a single outcome of a dice roll, call dice(). You should call dice() exactly num_rolls times in the body of roll_dice. Remember to call dice() exactly num_rolls times even if *Sow Sad* happens in the middle of rolling. In this way, you correctly simulate rolling all the dice together.

```
from random import randint

def roll_dice():
    final_sum = 0
    numrolls = 0
    while numrolls > 0 and numrolls <=10:
         final_sum= numrolls.dice()
         numrolls+=1
         return numrolls
         if numrolls.dice==1:
             numrolls=1
             print("SOW SAD, score for this turn is 1")
             final_sum+=numrolls
             return final_sum
    print(final_sum)
    
    def dice():
         value = 0
         while value > 0:
             return randint(1,6)
             return dice
```

Comment: hi, are you getting an error?

Comment: Based on your code. Because the indentions are all messed up this code makes absolutely no sense and is hard to see what you are trying to do.

Comment: You try to call `numrolls.dice()`, but `numrolls` is just the integer you defined a few lines prior. Your indentation seems wrong, you probably want `dice()` up a level, at the same level as `roll_dice()` and to call it just use `dice()` - it's unclear why you wanted to stick `numrolls` before it. You also have code after a `return` statement - that will never execute - try writing your code a bit at a time, adding things as you try them, instead of writing a whole bunch of code you don't really understand and just hoping for the best.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. It is [not possible to "help you" in an abstract way](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), and this is *not a discussion forum*, so your level of experience is irrelevant - this site is not about "being a programmer", it is about *the code*.

Comment: Anyway, there are many things in this code attempt that make little sense at all. I think you should try to solve a simpler problem first, and *make sure you can solve it on your own* first. Even if you have to start at the very beginning. Take smaller steps, *stop* whenever you stumble, fix the problem, and *make sure you understand* how you fixed it before proceeding.

Comment: But we cannot help you here without a clear question and a clear explanation of the problem. You should make sure other people can understand what you are talking about (what happens when you try to run the code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen? What do you mean by your question title - why are you asking us 'does this work?', if you need help fixing it? Doesn't that already tell you that it doesn't work? When you ask "why are these functions not defined?", what functions are you talking about, and why do you think they are "not defined"?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - sir you deserve my agreement on many levels ...  I'm sitting here trying to figure out how we can interpret the "question" in order to help; yet the most important aspect here is guidance towards self-help.

Comment: there's numerous errors and it's hard to tell what is being asked (`"how do I debug this"` is too general of a question for SO. i know everyone has to start somewhere, but basic debugging is something you should try on your own first. @KarlKnechtel's comment is a great explanation on how to approach debugging in smaller steps). one thing i'll mention in passing is that the way your function is written, the while loop won't execute in the first place

Answer (score 1):

> Implement the roll_dice function in hog.py. It takes two arguments: a positive integer called num_rolls giving the number of dice to roll and a dice function

As instructed, your function needs arguments

> It returns the number of points scored by rolling the dice that number of times in a turn

Assuming you're using a newer version of Python3, type hints can be added to functions

> either the sum of the outcomes or 1 ... call dice() exactly num_rolls times in the body of roll_dice. Remember to call dice() exactly num_rolls times even if Sow Sad happens in the middle of rolling.

list-comprehension can be used to run the function to roll multiple dice, and you can then check for ones or sum the lists

```
import random 

def dice() -> int:
    return random.randint(1, 6)  # assumed to be 6 sided die 

def roll_dice(num_rolls, dice_fn) -> int:
    # roll a number of times, and store the results 
    rolls = [dice_fn() for _ in range(num_rolls)] 
    # if there's a 1, that's the score, else add all roll values 
    return 1 if any(r == 1 for r in rolls) else sum(rolls) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_rolls = input("rolls: ") 
    # pass in the dice function, don't call it 
    print(roll_dice(int(num_rolls), dice))
```

Compared to your attempt ...

- functions ideally shouldn't be nested unless you have a good reason for it. That's more of an advanced topic
- `return` statements are used to return values to other places, and nothing after them will run within that same function
- Types matter. A function name should not be referenced by a number, or vice versa. This is a hard problem in Python to deal with
- Dot-notation is reserved for classes and modules. There are no classes defined. The only module you have here is the imported `random`

Comment: Or check `1 in rolls`.